# transformed XML from XSL missed attribute during copying

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL in our project. I am updating that for a new requirement.
I am copying a part of it in the post(XSL is pretty big around 1200 lines). 
In the below xml I am having a value under an element  InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader/Extrinsic/Attachment/URL.
By using the below xsl I am updating the value "URL" to "Updated URL".
But in the out put XML it didn't copy attribute name="invoicePDF".
Could any one please help why attribute didn't copy?

Thanks for your help.

Kitty.

-------------------Input XML-----------------

```
<InvoiceDetailRequest>  
    <InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>        
        <Extrinsic name="invoicePDF">
            <Attachment>
                <URL>
                    URL
                </URL>
            </Attachment>
        </Extrinsic>
    </InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>
</InvoiceDetailRequest>
```

----------------XSL---------------------

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="invoicePDFExtrinsic"
    select="InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='invoicePDF']" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">   <!-- Whenever any node or any attribute is matched -->
    <xsl:copy>     <!-- Copy the current node -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />  <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- And everything inside it -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *" />

        <xsl:if test="not($invoicePDFExtrinsic)">
            <xsl:element name="Extrinsic">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">invoicePDF</xsl:attribute>
                <Attachment>
                    <URL>
                        URL
                    </URL>
                </Attachment>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
    match="InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='invoicePDF']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$invoicePDFExtrinsic">
            <Attachment>
                    <URL>
                        Updated URL
                    </URL>
                </Attachment>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

--------------------Out put XML-------------------------------------------------------

```
<InvoiceDetailRequest>
    <InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>
        <Extrinsic>
            <Attachment>
                <URL>
                    Updated URL
                </URL>
            </Attachment>
        </Extrinsic>
    </InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>
</InvoiceDetailRequest>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the attribute(s) in any case then at least change

```
<xsl:template
    match="InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='invoicePDF']">
    <xsl:copy>
```

to

```
<xsl:template
    match="InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='invoicePDF']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
```

As you only want to manipulate the `URL` element it might be easier to write a template for that element instead of the approach you have taken.